# PDF Clown: creating lists

Tags: java, pdf, pdfclown

I'm looking to programmatically create PDF files using PDF Clown in Java. I require the use of lists, with bullet points. Is this possible using the current stable release of PDF Clown? If so, which class should I look at in the API Documentation? I have search for lists in the documentation however there is no mention of it.

The only way I can think of doing this without specific support is by using a BlockComposer with an X offset, this however would not have Bullet points. Any solutions?

I realise that this feature is planned for the next release of PDF Clown (0.2.0) however it is too far away for me to wait for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this
[image]

```
import org.pdfclown.documents.Document;
import org.pdfclown.documents.contents.colors.DeviceRGBColor;
import org.pdfclown.documents.contents.composition.*;

. . .

DocumentComposer composer = new DocumentComposer(document);

/*
  We decide that table cells sport a solid border by default (analogous 
  to CSS styles defined through an element type selector).
*/
composer.getStyle(Cell.class)
  .withBorder(new Border(
    new QuadColor(new DeviceRGBColor(0, 0, 0)),
    new QuadBorderStyle(BorderStyleEnum.Solid),
    new QuadLength(new Length(1)),
    new QuadCornerRadius()))
  .withPadding(new QuadLength(new Length(5)));

/*
  The list will be included in a section.
*/
Section section = new Section("Hello World, this is PDF Clown!");

/*
  This is the actual list composition.
*/
List list = new List(
  new ListItem("Item 1"),
  new ListItem("Item 2"),
  new ListItem(
    /* We decide that this list item has an arbitrary 5pt margin. */
    new Style().withMargin(new QuadLength(new Length(5))),
    "Item 3 (margin: 5pt)"
    ),
  new ListItem("Item 4"),
  new ListItem("Item 5"),
  new ListItem(
    /* We decide that this list item has a custom background color, border and padding. */
    new Style()
      .withBackground(new Background(new DeviceRGBColor(252f/255, 232f/255, 131f/255)))
      .withBorder(new Border(
        new QuadColor(new DeviceRGBColor(218f/255, 165f/255, 32f/255)),
        new QuadBorderStyle(BorderStyleEnum.Dotted),
        new QuadLength(new Length(2)),
        new QuadCornerRadius(new Size(5))
        ))
      .withPadding(new QuadLength(new Length(10))),
    new Paragraph("Item 6 (background, border, padding test + nested table)"
      + "\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor "
      + "incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud "
      + "exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure "
      + "dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. "
      + "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt "
      + "mollit anim id est laborum."),
    /* Nested table. */
    new Table(
      new Row(
        new Cell("Cell1,1"),
        new Cell("Cell1,2"),
        new Cell("Cell1,3"),
        new Cell("Cell1,4")
        ),
      new Row(
        new Cell("Cell2,1"),
        new Cell("Cell2,2").withColSpan(2),
        new Cell("Cell2,4")
        )
      )
  ),
  new ListItem(
    new Paragraph("Item 7 (sublist test)"),
    /* Nested list. */
    new List(
      /* We decide this nested list sports circle markers. */
      new Style().withListStyle(new ListStyle(ListStyleTypeEnum.Circle)),
      new ListItem("Sublist Item 1"),
      new ListItem(
        new Paragraph("Sublist Item 2 (Sub-sublist with multiple custom markers mimicking an ordered list)"),
        /* Level-2 nested list (custom ordered markers). */
        new List(
          /*
            We decide this nested list sports a set of custom numerical symbols mapped
            as octal codes to ZapfDingbats character set (see PDF Reference 1.7, § D.5, http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html).
          */
          new Style().withListStyle(new ListStyle(new char[]{0312, 0313, 0314, 0315, 0316, 0317, 0320, 0321, 0322})),
          new ListItem("Sub-sublist Item 1"),
          new ListItem("Sub-sublist Item 2"),
          new ListItem("Sub-sublist Item 3"),
          new ListItem("Sub-sublist Item 4"),
          new ListItem("Sub-sublist Item 5")
          )
        ),
      new ListItem("Sublist Item 3"),
      new ListItem(
        new Paragraph("Sublist Item 4 (Sub-sublist with decimal markers)"),
        /* Level-2 nested list (decimal markers). */
        new List(
          new Style().withListStyle(new ListStyle(ListStyleTypeEnum.Decimal)),
          new ListItem("Sub-sublist Item 1"),
          new ListItem(
            new Paragraph("Sub-sublist Item 2 (Sub-sub-sublist with lower-latin markers)"),
            /* Level-3 nested list (lower-latin markers). */
            new List(
              new Style().withListStyle(new ListStyle(ListStyleTypeEnum.LowerLatin)),
              new ListItem("Sub-sub-sublist Item 1"),
              new ListItem("Sub-sub-sublist Item 2"),
              new ListItem("Sub-sub-sublist Item 3"),
              new ListItem("Sub-sub-sublist Item 4"),
              new ListItem("Sub-sub-sublist Item 5")
              )
            ),
          new ListItem("Sub-sublist Item 3"),
          new ListItem("Sub-sublist Item 4"),
          new ListItem("Sub-sublist Item 5")
          )
        ),
      new ListItem("Sublist Item 5")
      ),
    new Paragraph("End of Item 7")
    ),
  new ListItem("Item 8")
  );
section.add(list);

composer.show(section);
composer.close();
```

Comment: This uses the new 0.2.0 composer, this isn't stable yet.